# Refresh wordpress post without reloading browser

Tags: posts

please is there any plugin or code that can refresh specific posts without reloading the browser...like livescore websites

```
<?php

if(is_single( ’17’ ))
{
    echo ‘<META HTTP-EQUIV=”REFRESH” CONTENT=”10″>’ ;
}
?>
```

17 is post id while 10 is the refresh time in seconds

above code works well but keeps reloading the browser

Comment: Start here:  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: couldn't understand

Comment: Yep you need JavaScript/Ajax to do this. There are React-based WordPress themes out there too that will do this out of the box if you aren't keen on coding.

Comment: could you give any example of themes with this feature

Comment: While jdm & Nathaniel are right, I would say using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) is probably the more modern approach.